# Fundamental group of configuration space of gauge theories

Tags: field-theory, gauge-theory, group-theory, topology, topological-field-theory

If I consider the space of all the gauge fields $A_{\mu}$ (call this $A$) and a proper gauge group $\Omega_*$, I know that the fundamental group $\pi_1(A)=0$ and the for the gauge group, for example $SU(2)$ I have $\pi_3(\Omega_*)=(Z,+)$. So the question is:
how can I calculate the fundamental group of the configuration space wich is $Q=A/\Omega_*$?

Comment: Use the long exact sequence of homotopy groups for a fibre bundle. Also I wouldn't call SU(2) as $\Omega_*$ - assuming that by "proper gauge group" you mean the "group of gauge transformations that go to the identity at infinity". You *can* relate $\pi_0(\Omega_*)$ to $\pi_3(\mathrm{SU}(2))$ however, which is precisely what you need to use the exact sequence.